# PostgreSQL command for dropping all views and functions owned by role?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a command in PostgreSQL for dropping all views and functions owned by a particular role? I don't understand how all the internal tables are connected together so that I can create such a command.

Answer (score 1):

Drop views:

```
create function drop_views_by_owner(owner regrole, do_drop boolean default true)
returns setof text language plpgsql as $$
declare r text;
begin
    for r in 
        select format('%s.%s', nspname, relname)
        from pg_class c
        join pg_namespace n on n.oid = relnamespace
        where c.relowner = $1
        and relkind = 'v'
    loop
        if do_drop then
            execute format('drop view %s', r);
        end if;
        return next r;
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Drop functions:

```
create function drop_functions_by_owner(owner regrole, do_drop boolean default true)
returns setof text language plpgsql as $$
declare r text;
begin
    for r in 
        select format('%s.%s(%s)', 
            nspname, proname, pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid))
        from pg_proc p
        join pg_namespace n on n.oid = pronamespace
        where p.proowner = $1
    loop
        if do_drop then
            execute format('drop function %s', r);
        end if;
        return next r;
    end loop;
end $$;
```

If the second argument is `false` the function does not drop the objects:

```
select drop_views_by_owner('newuser');            -- list views and drop them
select drop_views_by_owner('newuser', false);     -- only list views    

select drop_functions_by_owner('newuser');        -- list functions and drop them
select drop_functions_by_owner('newuser', false); -- only list functions
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I was really looking/hoping for a PostgreSQL command.

Answer (score 0):

If your user only owns views and functions, you can simply :

```
DROP OWNED BY your_role;
```

You must do it for each and every database in your cluster where your user owns an object.

You might find this documentation usefull: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/role-removal.html

Comment: Looks dangerous.  It could have unforeseen consequences.

Comment: It is indeed dangerous, but if you need to drop all objects owned by a user to be abble to drop your user, it can become very handy.